# linux kernel compilation: ERROR: "function" [path/to/module/module.ko] undefined

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, linker-errors

I have a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625685/linux-kernel-module-linker-warnings-warning-function-module-undefin) one, only for me it's an error not a warning. I'm building linux-4.8.5 with a [patch](https://github.com/TheDrHax/t100ta-kernel/commit/e32f79e79e319ba48bb03a0963c257b66568276e) applied to one module. I get:

```
ERROR: "intel_soc_pmic_readb" [drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko] undefined!
ERROR: "intel_soc_pmic_writeb" [drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko] undefined!
scripts/Makefile.modpost:91: recipe for target '__modpost' failed
make[1]: *** [__modpost] Error 1
Makefile:1201: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

In the other question they say something about KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS and documentation is supposed to be in Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt. But reading this file, this seems only to apply to modules not included in linux itself?

The functions are defined like

```
int function(){
    do_stuff;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(function);
```

then there is the declaration

```
 int function();
```

in a .h file in the include folder and it's called like

```
 #include <the_aforementioned_file.h>
//stuff
function();
```

from a file in the same folder as the definition of the function. There are no other occurrences of the function name in the whole source tree.

And I really just don't see the mistake. Most likely I'm not looking in the right place, I guess.

Comment: Are you sure that module defining given symbol is actually built? It requires configuration option `CONFIG_INTEL_SOC_PMIC`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That was the problem. o.O And I would have never thought to look for it, I was convinced that *of course* this module was being built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in a comment by Tsyvarev, this error is caused because the module in question is not being built, it requires the option `CONFIG_INTEL_SOC_PMIC`.

Comment: Similar question and answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812418/kernel-driver-external-modules-not-building-completely